# AVR32DA VIH threshold

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, avr, logic-level

I am looking into using an AVR32DA48 MCU for a design. The MCU will be powered at 5V and needs to interface with an IC at 3.3V. The IC is 5V tolerant and I am trying to figure out if a level translator is required for the IC to MCU communication.

According to the [AVR32DA datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/AVR32DA28-32-48-Data-Sheet-40002228B.pdf), on page 565, the *Table 37-7. I/O Pin Specifications* states that the I/O ports require 0.8xVDD minimum for VIH, which in this case means 4V. On page 605, though, the graph in *Figure 38-74 Input Pin with Schmitt Trigger - Minimum VIH vs. VDD*, reveals that the minimum VIH for 5V is nominally around 2.8V.

How is this discrepancy explained?

Comment: The same is true for VIL. Did you ask Microchip? You might have found an error in the data sheet. Did you search for an errata document?

Comment: No, I did not ask, because I have assumed that there is something wrong with my interpretation of the data and posted here so someone can point it out. After all, this is a fundamental property of the MCU, and if it actually turns out to be an error that went unnoticed for so long I will be extremely surprised. There is an errata document that addresses some issues in the datasheet, but not anything specific to that. (btw, why they have an errata about the datasheet and don't revise the document itself I cannot understand, but meh)

Comment: Well, data sheets are written by engineers, and engineers are humans, and humans make errors, and engineers are controlled by businessmen, and businessmen have no sense for correct data sheets. My interpretation is the same as yours, and I see the same discrepancy. -- Anyway, you want to know, therefore I suggest that you ask them.

Comment: True, true... Yes, I opened a support case yesterday at their website, let's see what their feedback is...

Comment: Did you get the answer from Microchip support?

Comment: @G36 Nope, not yet. They updated me around 10 days ago that "internal team is now notified" and "when a clarification is received" I will be updated. Thankfully I have switched development to be based on AVR32DB48, imagine if I had to wait...

Comment: Strange but I guess that the Microchip support team does not know the Atmel AVR chips. I wonder if you asked about PIC mcu, would you also have to wait so long for an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a real-world measurement using AVR32DD28.

Using this setup:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhQu5w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And I used this simple code:

```c
#include <avr/io.h>


int main(void)
{
    PORTD_DIRSET = (1 << PIN7_bp);
    
    while (1) 
    {
        PORTD_OUT = PORTA_IN; 
    }
}
```

And the voltmeter shows that the \$V_{IH}\$ is aroud \$2.78V\$

And \$V_{IL}\$ around \$2V\$

So it seems to match the typical value shown in the datasheet.
But again we have to remember that this is a typical value. And it will very form device to devise and with the temperature (VIH will increase for lower temperature).
And maybe this is why they say that  \$V_{IH} = 0.8 \:VDD\$ to stay on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your measurements seem to be in line with the graph on page 605. According to that graph, the worst case scenario depicted by the blue line (-40 C + 3σ) does not exceed 3V. So I would expect that to stay on the safe side then the upper threshold would be calculated as VIH = 0.6xVDD, or some slightly higher value.

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer since it clarifies which is the actual threshold and I will edit the original post to also provide the feedback I get from the manufacturer for reference.

Comment: Have you considered using MCU with "Multi-Voltage I/O function"? For example a AVR32DB48 siers? https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-40910A7E-D42A-4D4C-B9C2-D8614E3BC666-en-US-3/index.html?GUID-0120E9BA-42D3-40C9-802F-1B297E3ADDF6

Comment: I was not aware of the MVIO functionality. This actually is a good solution for my case, thanks for the suggestion!